# How to execute custom controller action for product in magento2?

Tags: product, magento2.3, controllers, product-list, action

I would like to write some custom code product actions in a controller is executed.

When I have click on the product than showing multiple brands and after that click on brand then show product detail page. I am not able to how to achieve this functionality

Please give me any solution?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For this, in product listing click you have to set your custom controller URL (brands) (in that URL you have also pass product id). 
When any of click any of the product then first it's going on your custom module.

After that for brand selection send data to the product view page.

I hope so it's use full.

Comment: I will try to achieve this functionality. Thanks, @Sweety Masmiya

Comment: Are you got any success for this?

Comment: Work In Progress.....!

Comment: We have to achieve this functionality.@Sweety Masmiya